# Clicking away from userform open text box VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am not very good with userforms so hopefully this is an easy question.

I have a userform in a spreadsheet that opens with

UserForm1.Show False

To ensure excel can still be used while it is open. What I would like to happen is that whenever you click away from (but not close) the userform a text box is opened asking if you want to maintain the edited values or not. I can't figure out how to initiate more code when the userform is no long the point of interest. Usually items on userforms have enter and exit which I believe would do what I need but I can't find the equivalent for the actual userform.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the Userform_Deactivate event

Comment: I did experiment a little with deactivate but it doesn't appear to work. I just input 
Private Sub UserForm_Deactivate()
UserForm3.Show
End Sub

Comment: Perhaps the lost focus event then?

Answer (score 1):

To allow a user to enter values into excel while a form is visible, you will need to update the ShowModal property on the userform to false.

[image]

Or as you are showing the userform, you can show it vbModeless.

```
UserForm.Show vbModeless
```

Comment: I think my questions was misunderstood, my userform is already modeless. I have decided to do it a different way now as I can't find the answer but thanks for your help.